# Get AWS config logs to S3 using Amazon Cloudwatch events or CloudTrail

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-config

I am looking to move AWS config logs to S3. Any input how can I do that using AWS CloudWatch or CloudTrail using Python.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup **AWS Config you have provide  S3 bucket** for its logs. If done in console, the bucket can be created on the spot with the correct bucket policy.

For `boto3` in python you have to **create bucket first** and setup a correct bucket policy as shown here:

- [Granting AWS Config access to the Amazon S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html#granting-access-in-another-account)